# Merging files in MS Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I've been using

```
for %i in (.\*.prt) do echo %i >> newfile.prt && type %i >> newfile.prt
```

to concentate many many files in Command Prompt. Using this one because it adds the file name before each individual file. Problem is it ends up duplicating. I think that's because it's putting it in the same folder. How can I amend this script to dump it into a different folder?

Comment: Um, `>> ..\otherdir\newfile.prt`?

Answer (score 0):

Reference the different directory instead...  Example:

```
for %%i in (*.prt) do (
   echo %%i>> "<OTHER_DIRECTORY>\newfile.prt"
   type %%i>> "<OTHER_DIRECTORY>\newfile.prt"
)
```

Or if not in a batch file:

```
for %i in (*.prt) do echo %i>> "<OTHER_DIRECTORY>\newfile.prt" && type %i>> "<OTHER_DIRECTORY>\newfile.prt"
```